# Insert string from variable containing "\n"s without replacing with newline literals

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a string that I'm capturing from a curl command to a variable. The string includes some javascript and newline codes (`\n`). How can I insert that text into a file, at a specific line number, without sed or awk either choking on the sequences or processing them into literal new lines? Here's what I have so far:

```
AGENT=`curl -s -X GET 'https://some.web.site/api/blah.json | jq '.blah[].javascript'`
LOC=`grep -n "locationmatchstring" file.htm | cut -d : -f 1`

awk -v line=$LOC -v text="$AGENT" '{print} NR==line{printf "    " text}' file.htm
```

The gist is that I'm pulling the script from the json source and inserting it into the html page at the correct location, based on a location match string, as a new line after the location match. I'm also adding the 4 spaces before the captured string so that it lines up with the spacing used in the html file. I've tried some variations on `text="$AGENT"`, like `text=$AGENT`, `text=${AGENT}`, `text='"$AGENT"'`, all of which were no help obviously. I would like it all to push straight into a single long line in the html file, and keep the `\n`'s where they are without expanding them.

Thoughts? And thanks!

Comment: "Keep the \n's where they are" -- you mean the resulting html will have `\n` and not linebreaks?

Comment: `line="$LOC"`, with the quotes -- that way the shell won't string-split and glob-expand your variable's value before passing it to `awk`. Always, *always*, **always** quote your expansions.

Comment: The original text used the word "newline" to refer to `\n` sequences, *and also* to refer to literal newlines. I've tried to edit to avoid that confusion, by using the term only for the latter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry about the newline/new line, I could have sworn I spaced the latter. Fixing it. And thanks for the coaching on the variables.

Comment: Ahh; I understand a little better how the original wording came about. "Newline" is not exclusively used to refer to `\n` sequences -- a `\n` expands to a newline, but in the same sense that `\t` expands to a tab; the newline is no more the `\n` than the `\t` is itself a tab. Supporting this -- in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, you can see `\n` described as an instruction to `Write a <newline>`; this would make no sense as an instruction to write itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
var='foo\nbar'
```

Note the difference:

```
$ awk -v var="$var" 'BEGIN{print "<" var ">"}'
<foo
bar>

$ var="$var" awk 'BEGIN{var=ENVIRON["var"]; print "<" var ">"}'
<foo\nbar>

$ awk 'BEGIN{var=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""; print "<" var ">"}' "$var"
<foo\nbar>
```

See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for details.

Never do `printf <input data>` btw unless you have a VERY specific purpose in mind and fully understand all of the caveats/implications. Instead do `printf "%s", <input data>` - imagine the difference if/when `<input data>` includes printf formatting chars like `%s`.

Also always quotes your shell variables (google it) never use all upper case for non-exported shell variables by convention and to avoid clashing with environment variables.

So assuming you use loc instead of LOC and agent instead of AGENT in the assignment above it, your entire awk line would be (assuming your awk supports ENVIRON otherwise use the ARGV approach above):

```
agent="$agent" awk -v line="$loc" 'BEGIN{text=ENVIRON["agent"]} {print} NR==line{printf "    %s", text}' file.htm
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the well informed answer. I haven't really tried to do much of anything with AWK before and this post helped me dig in a lot more.